# python and pandas: use bin counts from one df to get similarly binned counts from another df with no shared columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given df1, I know how to get binned value counts using `.value_counts()`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [0.1, 0.11, 0.2, 0.3, 0.33, 0.6, 0.66, 0.7, 0.9, 1],
'another_column': ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'orange']})

df1['numbers'].value_counts(bins=[0, 0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1])
```

result:

```
(0.6, 0.7]       2
(0.1, 0.2]       2
(0.9, 1.0]       1
(0.8, 0.9]       1
(0.5, 0.6]       1
(0.3, 0.4]       1
(0.2, 0.3]       1
(-0.001, 0.1]    1
(0.7, 0.8]       0
(0.4, 0.5]       0
Name: numbers, dtype: int64
```

Given another df much larger than df1 (example below):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [0.1, 0.11, 0.2, 0.3, 0.33, 0.6, 0.66, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.11, 0.2, 0.3, 0.33, 0.6, 0.66, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.11, 0.2, 0.3, 0.33, 0.6, 0.66, 0.7, 0.98],
'nonshared_column': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'fish', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'fish', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'fish']})
```

I want to take the bins from df1 to filter df2, so the output df is a subset of df2 that matches bins from df1,

so the output df will have 1 row with 'numbers' values between 0-0.1, 2 rows with 'numbers' values between 0.1-0.2 ... all the way to 1 row with 'numbers' values between 0.9-1. The output df rows should include all the columns from df2 (the `nonshared_column` in this example, as well as the `numbers` column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with `bins` from index by `Series` called `s`:

```
s = df1['numbers'].value_counts(bins=[0, 0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1])

df2['new'] = pd.cut(df2['numbers'], bins=s.index)
print (df2)
    numbers nonshared_column            new
0      0.10              cat  (-0.001, 0.1]
1      0.11              dog     (0.1, 0.2]
2      0.20              cat     (0.1, 0.2]
3      0.30              dog     (0.2, 0.3]
4      0.33             fish     (0.3, 0.4]
5      0.60              cat     (0.5, 0.6]
6      0.66              dog     (0.6, 0.7]
7      0.70              dog     (0.6, 0.7]
8      0.90             fish     (0.8, 0.9]
9      0.10              cat  (-0.001, 0.1]
10     0.11              dog     (0.1, 0.2]
11     0.20              cat     (0.1, 0.2]
12     0.30              dog     (0.2, 0.3]
13     0.33             fish     (0.3, 0.4]
14     0.60              cat     (0.5, 0.6]
15     0.66              dog     (0.6, 0.7]
16     0.70              dog     (0.6, 0.7]
17     0.90             fish     (0.8, 0.9]
18     0.10              cat  (-0.001, 0.1]
19     0.11              dog     (0.1, 0.2]
20     0.20              cat     (0.1, 0.2]
21     0.30              dog     (0.2, 0.3]
22     0.33             fish     (0.3, 0.4]
23     0.60              cat     (0.5, 0.6]
24     0.66              dog     (0.6, 0.7]
25     0.70              dog     (0.6, 0.7]
26     0.98             fish     (0.9, 1.0]
```

Last if need count per all 3 columns:

```
df3 = df2.groupby(['numbers','nonshared_column','new'], observed=True).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df3)
   numbers nonshared_column            new  count
0     0.10              cat  (-0.001, 0.1]      3
1     0.11              dog     (0.1, 0.2]      3
2     0.20              cat     (0.1, 0.2]      3
3     0.30              dog     (0.2, 0.3]      3
4     0.33             fish     (0.3, 0.4]      3
5     0.60              cat     (0.5, 0.6]      3
6     0.66              dog     (0.6, 0.7]      3
7     0.70              dog     (0.6, 0.7]      3
8     0.90             fish     (0.8, 0.9]      2
9     0.98             fish     (0.9, 1.0]      1
```

EDIT:

If need same counts like `s` first use `sample` for random order of rows and then `head()` with map by `s` for filter by counts:

```
df2 = df2.sample(frac=1).groupby('new', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.head(s[x.name])).sort_index()
print (df2)
    numbers nonshared_column            new
2      0.20              cat     (0.1, 0.2]
3      0.30              dog     (0.2, 0.3]
4      0.33             fish     (0.3, 0.4]
9      0.10              cat  (-0.001, 0.1]
11     0.20              cat     (0.1, 0.2]
14     0.60              cat     (0.5, 0.6]
15     0.66              dog     (0.6, 0.7]
17     0.90             fish     (0.8, 0.9]
24     0.66              dog     (0.6, 0.7]
26     0.98             fish     (0.9, 1.0]
```

Comment: This works great for the first part! What about randomly selecting rows from df2 so that it has the same bin counts as df1?